# Python Error : TypeError: 'errstate' object is not callable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim

I am getting this error in the following code

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from gensim.models import Word2Vec 


filename2 = 'Models/mpl_model.sav'
loaded_model2 = joblib.load(filename2)
modell= Word2Vec.load("Models/cbow.model")
```

I am trying to load model from Models folder. I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: 'errstate' object is not callable
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mr_toot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 605, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/home/mr_toot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 529, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/mr_toot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/home/mr_toot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/home/mr_toot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1426, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
  File "/home/mr_toot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .philox import Philox
  File "philox.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.philox
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 397, in init numpy.random.bit_generator
TypeError: 'errstate' object is not callable
```

Update :

The error was solved by upgrading numpy. Model was dumped using a new version and 
I was loading it using an older version.

Comment: You are using ```joblib.load()``` which causes this error, you can check the docs https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html to be sure on what you are giving (*.sav SPSS file) is allowed and your folder permission is available for that specific file. Try run your console as root/administrator and try your code.

Comment: @furkanayd I get the same error for  modell= Word2Vec.load("Models/cbow.model")  after removing the joblib.load lines.